# Python: How to detect and isolate color text in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, text, colors

I am trying to extract the color of the text in order to remove everything else but that color text from the image. I am using pytesseract OCR to locate and read the text but the color of the text can be different. Currently I got the all the colors in the image and masking them till I can read the correct text but this is only in thousands of useless images. How can I extract the text color?

[image: color text]

```
# Get all image colors sorted
cimage = Image.open('z.jpg').convert('RGB')
colors = sorted(image.getcolors(image.size[0] * image.size[1]))
tol = 5     # Color tolerance

# mask out color
for i in range(len(colors)):
    color_mask = cv2.inRange(cimage, np.array([colors[i][1][2] - tol, colors[i][1][1] - tol, colors[i][1][0] - tol]), 
                                np.array([colors[i][1][2] + tol, colors[i][1][1] + tol, colors[i][1][0] + tol]))
    color_mask_inv = 255 - color_mask 
    color_thresh = cv2.cvtColor(color_mask_inv, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    #color_thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(cimage, cimage, mask = color_mask )
    cv2.imshow('image',color_thresh)
```

Edit: Fix typo.

Comment: This is a interesting question, and I'd like to help, but I have a few clarifying questions: 1. is `cimage` supposed to be `image`? If so, I am getting an error on the cv2.inRange call, so if cimage is something else that would be useful information. 2. When you say "I am trying to extract the color of the text in order to remove everything else but that color text from the image" what output are you hoping to end up with? A white image with just the colored text from the initial image? Do you want one image or a set of images representing each color?

Comment: locate text, get multiple regions of interest. for each ROI, cluster the pixel colors in the region of interest. one cluster will be background, the other will be foreground. done.

Comment: 1. Yes Matt, cimage is image, the c got cut when copying.
2. The first part, one white image with just the colored text from the initial image.

Comment: You could probably threshold the color channels individually to find text of a particular color.